# Bootstrap overriding with bootstrap-rails gem with less

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to change the bg colour of the `.well`.

I have to override because `@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";` brings the css in from the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem, so I can't edit the raw bootstrap file.

Is there a way to override it using less without doing something like:

```
.well {
    background: red;
}
```

(Because this way there are two `.well` definitions given to the browser - this one above and the original from bootstrap)

It looks like bootstrap does have a way of overriding: for instance to change the body's background I can use `@bodyBackground`. But i'm not sure what the definitions are for the `.well` which isn't as well documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't using any variables like `@bodyBackround` inside the `.well` definition ([wells.less](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/wells.less)). So this nice and easy solution is no option for you.